# How can i catch the error when the api reaches its daily limit in JS?

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to catch the specific error when a certain API key **expires** or it reaches its **daily response limit**(assuming 1000 per day).

```
const moviesearchEngine=()=>{
    let searchBox = document.querySelector('.searchBox');
    let movieTitle = document.querySelector('.movieTitle');
    let yearofRelease = document.querySelector('.yearofRelease');
    let genre = document.querySelector('.genre');
    let director = document.querySelector('.director');
    let plot = document.querySelector('.plot');

    const apiCall = ()=>{
        let params = new URLSearchParams({
            t:searchBox.value,
            apikey:`key`
        })
        let api = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?${params}`;

        //fetching the api orelse showing the error
        fetch(api).then((response)=>{
                return response.json();
        }).then((data)=>{
            //assigning the data to variable
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
    apiCall();
}
```

Comment: Why not ask the author to put that in the response if it is not already there?

Comment: Even if you reach your daily limit you would get a response but for other scenario why cant you put conditions and code around that response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Go through your desired API's documention and you would be looking for this sort of information mentioned in the **Usage limits** section of [this api page](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json). If you fail to find anything useful then please contact the support of your desired API.

Then you can proceed like this -

```
var endpoint = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=status,message,countryCode';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if(response.status !== 'success') {
            console.log('query failed: ' + response.message);
            return
        }
        // Redirect
        if(response.countryCode == "US") {
            window.location.replace("https://google.com/");
        }
        if(response.countryCode == "CA") {
            window.location.replace("https://google.ca/");
        }
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', endpoint, true);
xhr.send();
```

[Source](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json)